# grep does not print filename of result for some files with special characters

Tags: macos, unix, grep

I have this particular file with special characters:

```
​
^S^H^B^R^MLong is here
^X^M
```

When I search for it via `grep -r "Long is here" .` it will give me the following as result, not revealing its file path:

```
Long is here
```

However, if I remove the `^S^H^B^R^M`, the file path will show up:

```
./CIQla:Long is here​
```

I'm using OSX.

What's going on here?

---

EDIT:

I tried it with both BSD grep (`grep 2.5.1-FreeBSD`) as GNU grep (`ggrep 2.26`)

Comment: what if you use `-H` as well to print the file name? In general, `grep` does not print the filename if there is just one match.

Comment: `-H` option is `default when there is more than one file to search`... I think those special characters are overwriting characters from grep output

Comment: @fedorqui `-H` does not make the file path show up, but `-l` does. However, it is still a mystery to me how those special characters can prevent grep from printing the file path...

Comment: Check `man grep` on how `-H` works, since it does show the file path show up. What `-l` does is to _just_ show the path.

Answer (score 4):

The ^M is a carriage return, which makes the terminal return to the beginning of the line. Essentially, it prints "./CIQla:", then several nonprinting characters, then ^M sends it to the beginning of the line, then it prints "Long is here" *over* the "./CIQla:".

If you want to be able to see the filename in the output, you need to pipe the result through something that'll make the ^M (and probably the other nonprinting characters) into something printable. Try these:

```
grep -r "Long is here" . | cat -v
grep -r "Long is here" . | more
```

Comment: `grep ... | od -c` will *really* make the extra characters visible.